# Reledpar – old "killnumber"

Tags: ledmac, eledpar, reledmac, reledpar

is there a way in the package "reledpar" to suppress the linenumber in a footnote? There was a way in the old "ledpar"-package, which was descriped in the manual (killnumber and so on, see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17198/ledmac-suppress-linenumber-in-footnote-or-add-some-text-to-the-apparatus)).
But this doen't work for me anymore (the code "ifledplinenum" seems to cause trouble).
Does anyone have a solution?

here is a running reledmac-example. The first footnote should not have the linenumber, the second footnote (in the same line) should have it. This was possible in the older versions with `\killnumber` etc. – Xnonumber works a little bit strange for me – I think I'm using it in a wrong way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac,reledpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{pages}

\begin{Leftside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart

Lorem \edtext{ipsum}{\Afootnote{Test}} dolor sit \edtext{amet}{\Afootnote{A further test}}, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. 

\pend

\endnumbering


\end{Leftside}
\end{pages}

\begin{pages}
\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis
facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet
mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices
augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. 

\pend


\endnumbering
\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}

\Pages


\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, my "Hello" and "I need some help" got lost.

Comment: Disable it in one footnote? disable it when the line number is the same as another footnote?  More context, and some actual, but minimal code, would be useful.  There is `\Xnonumber[<s>]` in `reledmac` ... but is it what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the link to the old example/minimal code would be enough. I just want exactly the same: To suppress the linenumber once in one footnote. I cannot follow all the manuals to ledmac, eledmac, now reledmac with new commands.
\Xnonumber might be what I'm looking for, but what is meant by [<s>]?

Comment: The commands for `ledmac` and `reledmac` are not exactly the same. Can you post a minimal example that relies on `reledmac`?

Comment: hi @CarstenBinder some reaction to my answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use optional argument of \Afootnote.

`\edtext{lemma}{\Afootnote[nonum]{line with no num}}`

cf. §5.2.2 of the handbook

Comment: Thank you – haven't seen that in the handbook, it's the solution. Sorry for my delay – I had an accident.

Comment: your welcome ;-) don't forget to valide the answer (and to up it)